# MySQL - Basic Prepared Statement EXECUTE problems in procedure

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-5.7

```
CREATE TABLE User (id int, name varchar(100));
INSERT INTO User VALUES (1, 'Sri');   

 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`.`x`()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE x VARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE y VARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE value INT;
        SET x := ' id = 1';
        SET @d = x;
        SET z := CONCAT(' name = ',QUOTE('Sri'));
        SET @d1 = z;
        SELECT @d, @d1;
    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT count(*) into @lv_name from User WHERE ? AND ?';
    EXECUTE stmt using @d,@d1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    SELECT @lv_name;
    END;
```

Hi, Im not getting the result as 1 in the `@lv_name`. May I know what's wrong with the approach. I need to definitely use the `col_name = val` in the variable. Please share dbfiddle if possible.

Comment: You cannot transfer code parts into the query text via USING - you may transfer parameter values only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare variable, you can add text and values directly into user defined variables.

Prepared statements are not substituting strings, they only suplement the values, so that you can run the query in a loop and only need to change the user defined variables

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `x`()
BEGIN
    SET @d = 1;
    SET @d1 = 'Sri';

    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT count(*) into @lv_name from User WHERE id = ? AND name = ?';
    EXECUTE stmt using @d,@d1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    SELECT @lv_name;
    END
```

There you can also do this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `x`()
BEGIN
        DECLARE value INT;
        DECLARE _x VARCHAR(1000);
        SET @d = 1;
        SET @d1 = 'Sri';
        SET @sqlx = 'SELECT count(*) into @lv_name from User WHERE ';
    IF 1 = 1 THEN
        SET @sqlx = CONCAT(@sqlx ,'name = ?');
    else
        SET @sqlx = CONCAT(@sqlx ,'id = ',@d1);
    END IF;
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlx;
    IF 1 = 1 THEN
        EXECUTE stmt using @d1;
    ELSe
        EXECUTE stmt using @d;
    END IF;
    
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    SELECT @lv_name;
END
```

But the number of arguments must be **exactly** like the number of question marks i the query

Comment: `DECLARE value INT;` - this variable is not used... and `value` is reserved word.

Comment: I know @Akina but the user is in a learnung phase and i don't know, why it is there and i don't know why he didn't use IN for the id and name, but we all start small, anmd need a leg up

Comment: Maybe it is safe to comment this statement and add a comment that this statement is ... mmm ... strange?

Comment: Hi. Actually I have a if else where i shouldn’t use name column name in the where condition. So i’m trying not to declare the query twice using that concat. that’s why i specifically mentioned that i need to use col = value thingy in the variable.